# Get top comments out of database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks like:

```
id|text|rating|TimeOfRating
```

for discription: if a user rates a comment with four points out of 5, 4 points are added to rating and to TimeOfRating 1 is added.

how ist it with php possible to filter out the 10 comments with the best rating?

Cheers!

Comment: what do u mean `TimeOfRation increases by 1.` ?

Comment: Why do you add 5 if someone gives it 4 points?

Comment: edited my question. hope now its clear!

Comment: @Michael it is still not clear. When you say "filter out" do you mean remove or only show the 10 comments with the best rating?

Comment: show...sry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the average rating:

```
SELECT
  id,
  text,
  (rating/TimeOfRating) AS score
FROM tablename
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: why `(rating/TimeOfRating)` ?

Comment: DarthVader, I assume Michael wants the average rating.

Comment: well his question doesnt make sense. and dividing rating to TimeOfRating doesnt as well.

Comment: I'm really confused. Exactly how does guessing the OP wanted an average get an accept?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, this satisfies your requirement.

```
SELECT id, text, rating, TimeOfRating
FROM
    (SELECT id, text
    CASE
            WHEN rating = 4 THEN rating + 5
            ELSE rating
        END AS rating,
    CASE
            WHEN rating = 4 THEN TimeOfRating + 1
            ELSE TimeOfRating
        END AS TimeOfRating
    FROM pickles) a
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 10
```

What type of column is `TimeOfRating`?